# openlayers3 How can I draw a feature and get the area of the feature

Tags: openlayers-3

```
draw.on('drawend',function(event){
            var geom = event.feature.getGeometry();
            setTimeout(function(){
                if (select.value == "LineString") {
                    output = formatLength(geom);
                }else if(select.value == "Polygon"){
                    output = geom.getArea();
                }
                alert(output);
            }, 300);
```

I use the openlayers3 to draw a feature, and I want to get the area or length of the feature.I can get length,and alert it,But cannot get the area,and there is no problem occur.